# Can I host (self host) a WCF Service in a Windows Service and expose it via http?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, windows-services

I am new to WCF.. is this possible and if its consumed via external web applications is it better go with IIS and http, ie service hosted by an ASP.NET MVC application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can host a WCF service in a windows service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

I'd say that if you can host it in iis it is probably better.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that hosting a WCF Service in a Windows Services means it can still be exposed via http port 80 to external applications?

Comment: That is a good question, I'd assume that the service would have to run as an administrative user to bind to a port under 1024. I could very well be wrong though.

Comment: I know for a fact that self-hosting on port 80 (or even 443) is not a problem on XP/Server 2003, but there may be port reservation commands that need to be run on W7/S2008.

Comment: There's nothing about WCF or the Windows service itself that restricts you from exposing it via http port 80.  However, the operating system, firewall, antivirus, etc. may cause headaches that must be dealt with.