# Call Windows Service from Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-services, msmq

I have a windows service created and installed.  I want to call it from my MVC controller, as I am implementing MSMQ messaging service, so need to call Windows service.

Comment: What does the windows service do? I trust you are aware that you can write to a message queue directly from a web-application?

Comment: [See this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247529/asp-net-mvc-4-application-to-call-windows-service). And [this interesting blog ](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/) that while will not directly solve your issue, is an interesting read relating to what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Ideally the windows service should host a WCF service that your web application can contact. From there, it's a matter of creating a client, making the WCF call (to the service) and sending/receiving the information necessary.</strike>

Sorry, didn't see [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx) until later. How about something like:

```
MessageQueueTransaction msgTx = new MessageQueueTransaction();
MessageQueue msgQ = new MessageQueue(@".\private$\Orders");
msgTx.Begin();
try
{
   msgQ.Send("First Message",msgTx);
   msgQ.Send("Second Message",msgTx);
   msgTx.Commit();
}
catch
{
   msgTx.Abort();
}
finally
{
   msgQ.Close();
}
```

Then, of course, have a method of reading the messages in the service.

Answer (score 0):

there is a .net library to do that as push notifications, it's name is signalr

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please extend your answer so it is more useful?